How to handle login exceptions for vivox in unity3d?
I'm developing a multiplayer game with Vivox 16.3.0 integration, where I've successfully implemented events such as

VivoxService.Instance.ConnectionFailedToRecover
VivoxService.Instance.ConnectionRecovered
VivoxService.Instance.ConnectionRecovering

These events are functioning as expected.
However, when the network disconnects for an extended period, I encounter the following exception:
[Vivox]: HandleAccountLoginStateChangeEvt: Unity.Services.Vivox.VivoxApiException: Automatic Reconnection Failure (10101)
While I understand this exception is expected behavior, it causes errors within Unity. I'm unsure about the appropriate approach to handle this situation. Where should I implement try/catch blocks, or what other strategies could I employ to prevent Unity from becoming unresponsive due to these errors?
My implementation closely follows the guidelines provided in the following documentation: link to the guide.
Any advice on how to effectively manage such exceptions to ensure uninterrupted gameplay within Unity would be greatly appreciated.
Expectations-
The above exception should be handled so that unity does not get stuck on any errors
